# Join multiple related lists in reports

Tags: apex, visualforce

I was wondering if this was feasible but i have an object that contains two related lists. Am i able to create a report from data from both related lists into one report? Or will i have 2 different reports?

A has related list b. A has related list c.

Reports Generated:

A with b. A with c.

Anyway to get, A with bc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try creating a report with the **Joined** format.  A joined report will have two reports with the same "base"/common data -- i.e. the records in the Master-object (object `A` in your example) but each separate report (that's joined at at the end by the common Maser-record) is about one of those Master-Detail Relationships.

You *may* be able to do this without using the Joined format if you are able to create a Report Type that encompasses the three objects in question.

Try to create a `Report Type`, go to  <kbd>Setup</kbd>  --->  <kbd>Create</kbd>  ---->  <kbd>Report Types</kbd> .  Have the new `Report Type`'s `Primary Object` be the Master Object (object `A` in your example), and try to add both objects as secondary/tertiary objects.

Comment: Yup managed to get it working, Had to enable Report builder

Comment: Hi  can you please share the resolution steps in detail? what made it work..joined report or custom report type?