# Adding Multiple Objects to Reports and Showing Fields

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I am looking to report on 3 objects: A, B, C. Further, I want to generate a single report that can show all the fields on A, B, and C.

Object A and B are related and objects A and C are related. However, B and C are not related. On object C, there is a look-up relation to A, but there is no look-up relation to object C on A (i.e. there is no field on A that contains C).

I know I can use joined tables per this stackexchange answer: [Join multiple related lists in reports](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29338/join-multiple-related-lists-in-reports/29353#29353). The reason this solution doesn't work for me is that I want to show a tabular format rather than as a joined table.

I also can't make a custom report where I have A, B, and C as primary, secondary, and tertiary objects respectively because of my data model.

I have also tried making a report with A and B and then using a cross object filter with a "with" statement to find C. While that works, it can't show the field names of C on the report, which I want.

Finally, I know that I can add a field that is a look up to C on A but I am looking to avoid that due to my org's design (though if this is the only way around my problem, then my org's design won't matter).

I think I have exhausted the solutions I can think of. Are there any solutions that other people have found?

Comment: i've used Conga Composer into excel templates with vlookups and/or pivot tables to generate what you want (excel does the after-the-fact relationships into your desired table layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A and B are related, does Obj A has the lookup to Obj B? IF so you can create a custom Report Type Using Main Obj as C and Include Obj A + You can include all fields related to a Lookup Field i.e., For Obj B. This way you can achieve your report

Or You can go for a VisualForce Page if the Obj A doesnt have a lookup field of Obj B.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I went back and looked at our design and generating a report using out-of-the-box features would be impossible. We might be going down a separate path. However, your solution with VF does help!